# Redux Framework Array Options Value

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I have just started using the Redux Framework for development on a theme. I having a bit of trouble understanding a certain part of the array, if its required, and whats the purpose of it. As an example:

```
array(
    'id'       => 'opt-checkbox-sidebar',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'title'    => __( 'Multi Checkbox Option (with sidebar data)', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'subtitle' => __( 'No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'     => __( 'This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'data'     => 'sidebars'
),
```

The part where it says 'redux-framework-demo' on the title, subtitle, and desc lines, is this required? and what does it do? I can't seem to find much information regarding this.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

text domain for translations.  I would refer to the WordPress Codex for detailed information.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, cause its only shown on the text strings. Thanks so much!